# How to upload a new version of a binary file to GitHub repo througn GitHub Web interface

Tags: git, github, upload

I do not find an interface control to upload a new version of a binary file to a GitHub repo. Is there any?

[image: GITHUB interface]

The button with the three dots:

[image: The button with three dots]

Comment: Use the button with the three dots. In there you can find “upload files”

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not have an Upload option. I have added an illustration

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where this is a binary. I will add a screenshot for that to make it more clear. but I can only do that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that at the folder level, not from the file level. Got to "Add file" and then "Upload file". If the file has the same name, it will be used to overwrite the existing file. Not that I am at the folder level on the left.

[image: Screenshot of GitHub UI with Add file --> Upload files option]